# ProgressBar not updating from async task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm trying to transition an old project from BackgroundWorker to async/await but am really struggling to get the progressbar to update. I followed this article but can't get it to work as they do:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx

Here is my code:

```
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnStart.Enabled = false;
    pb.Show();
    btnCancel.Enabled = true;

    var progressIndicator = new Progress<int>(ReportProgress);
    List<string> updates = Directory.GetFiles(txtInput.Text).ToList();

    try
    {
        await ProcessUpdates(updates, progressIndicator, _cts.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Operation Cancelled");
    }

    btnStart.Enabled = true;
    pb.Hide();
    btnCancel.Enabled = false;


}

async Task<int> ProcessUpdates(List<string> updatePaths, IProgress<int> progress, CancellationToken ct)
{
    int total = updatePaths.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < updatePaths.Count; i++)
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        string update = updatePaths[i];
        ssFile.Text = $"Processing update: {Path.GetFileName(update)}";

        using (Stream source = File.Open(update, FileMode.Open))
        using (Stream destination = File.Create(txtOutput.Text + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(update)))
        {
            await source.CopyToAsync(destination);
        }

        progress?.Report((i / total) * 100);
    }

    return total;
}

private void ReportProgress(int value)
{
    pb.Value = value;
}

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _cts.Cancel();
}
```

Where am I going wrong? It's driving me mad. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Are you getting an error? Or is the progress bar not updating?

Comment: Sorry, forgot a pretty crucial bit of information. The progressbar doesn't update, but the rest of the GUI (status strip) is. The progressbar doesn't even jump from 0-100, it just does nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(i / total) * 100` performs integer division, which always truncates the decimal portion, resulting in a value of `0` because `i` is less than `total`.

Either use `float` or change the order of operations: `i * 100 / total`

Comment: Thank you so much. I was convinced it was something async related because I'm new to it, when in fact it was staring me right in the face. Working perfectly now.

Comment: @Dark Falcon, badass man. Thanks for pointing it out. I too was convinced it was a threading or UI issue. Thanks man!